# Why did the dove return to the ark the 2nd time?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-noach

When Noach sent the dove the [first time](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0108.htm#8), the Torah states that the dove could not find a place to rest her leg. This seems to be the reason as to why it returned to the ark.

After the 2nd trip, we see that the dove returned to the ark with an olive branch. This implies that there was a place for the dove to rest. If so, why did the dove return to the ark, anyway?

Comment: I always thought it meant that the branch was sticking it, but too weak to hold the doves weight

Answer (score 4):

*Haamek Davar* explains that it returned with a leaf because Noah was expecting a response. The next time, it had nothing new to report so didn't return.